# Почему не работает каст int(&)[Rs][Cs] к int**?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, шаблоны-с++, типы-данных

Экспериментировал, пытался сделать небольшой хак:

```
void int_array_2d_show_impl(int** array, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
{
    for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        for(std::size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            std::clog << array[row][col]
                      << (col == cols-1 ? '\n' : ' ');
}

template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
void int_array_2d_show_ref(int (&array)[Rows][Cols])
{
    int_array_2d_show_impl((int**)array,Rows,Cols);
}
```

Но это не работает. Статический анализатор пишет, что `static_cast` не позволяет кастить `int(*)[N]` к `int**`. Сишный каст, естественно, работает, но ломает код, и `int_array_2d_show_impl` ничего не выводит. Почему так происходит? В чем тут UB? Они по разному в памяти хранятся чтоли? Такой код не выводит ничего, но выполняется без compile time и без run time ошибок. Хотя бы мусора же должен был вывести...

**Post Scriptum:** Получилось так:

```
void int_array_2d_show_impl(int* array, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
{
    for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        for(std::size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            std::clog << array[row*cols+col]
                      << (col == cols-1 ? '\n' : ' ');
}

template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
void int_array_2d_show_ref(int (&array)[Rows][Cols])
{
    int_array_2d_show_impl(*array,Rows,Cols);
}
```

Comment: Потому что `int[Rows][Cols]` и `int**` - это принципиально разные типы!!!

Comment: @Harry, я знаю, и что? Типы типами, но в памяти то они одинаково хранятся по идее. Напрмиер, int[N] к int* каститься без проблем, тут получается тоже самое, но немножко сложнее. Тут массив интов, а там массив указателей на инты... Одно и то же ведь.

Comment: Не одинаково хранятся

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `int[Rows][Cols]` и `int**` - это принципиально разные типы, **по-разному** хранящиеся в памяти.

В первом случае - это одна непрерывная область памяти, в которой выражения типа `a[3][2]` рассчитывает сам компилятор, исходя из того, что тип `int[Rows][Cols]` - это указатель на `int[Cols]` (!), а не на `int*`.

В `int**` мы имеем массив указателей, каждый их которых указывает на какой-то массив `int`'ов.

Вот примерный набросок размещения в памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще раз - самое главное - в `int[Rows][Col]` вы имеете дело не с указателями на указатели на `int`, а с указателями на `int[Cols]`. А это совершенно разные типы!

Comment: Да туплю, по идее нужно его просто к `int*` скастить. Интересно, это будет UB или нет...

Comment: Просто к `int*` - можно, но `array[row][col]` вы писать не сможете. Только `array[row*Cols+col]`.

Comment: Да, знаю, спасибо. Иногда забываю основы=))

Comment: @megorit И да, формально это будет UB. Чтобы убедиться, попробуйте сделать это в constexpr-функции: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1G34aq

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не совсем понимаю, при чем тут `constexpr`?

Comment: @megorit В constexpr строго проверяются гранцы массивов. Еще вот тут можно почитать: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111570/discussion-on-answer-by-harry------